# Is there a way for @MockBean to be used for a single test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a new SpringBoot unit test which requires injecting a @MockBean which I added and is working as expected. But unfortunately, the mockbean is messing up with some of the existing tests causing them to fail. Is there any way I can inject @MockBean to the particular test alone so that the other tests are unaffected? Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about different test methods in one class, where you want to restrict the MockBean to one test method, or about tests in different classes?

Comment: Yeah, right they are different test methods in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a second test class which only contains a single test. The MockBean will then not affect the existing tests.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but there will be a lot of code duplication. I was so trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Sathesh common code can be moved to a separate class. Or you could utilize an abstract base class. Depends on the exact nature of the duplication.